# Citroen C5 2013 (X7) - Automatic Windshield Wipers won't turn off

Tags: windshield-wipers, citroen

Having trouble with Windshield Wipers on my Citroen C5 (X7) 2013 2.0 HDI 100KW. Today, all of a sudden the Wipers activated all on their own even when auto mode was disabled. Moving the wiper switch (leaver) in up or down position did not have any effect. It continued to run in slow automatic mode even when it said that automatic mode is disabled. It also continued to run with the car turned off and key out of the ignition. I had to detach my car battery to stop it.

After I reattached the car battery the manual Wiper mode started working again for a minute or two and then the issue started happening again and I lost again control. My best guess is that this is caused by the onboard computer. Probably during those 1-2minutes the manual mode works because computer is not started yet and when it startes the issue reemerges.

Any ideas what could it be? Faulty sensor, bad wiring, actual chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is gone for now. It seems that disconnecting car battery for about 8 hours helped reset things on the car.

## Update

After couple of days the issue reoccured again after a car wash. I drove the car to an electrician and when they disasembled the wiper compartment they found out that electric motors were all soaked in water becase the shaft was jammed with leaves and dirt so water got stuck. They cleaned the compartment and dried the wiper motors. So far so good.